# Laurent Series on a square annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am trying to prove the following problem: [[Source](http://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/graduate/qualifiers/exams/Sept%202015/AnalysisQRSept2015.pdf), page 2 problem 3]

> Let $S_6$ and $S_7$ be the open squares centered at the origin of side
>   length 6 and 7, respectively. Let $\Gamma_6$ and $\Gamma_7$ be the
>   boundary of $S_6$ and $S_7$, respectively, and let $\Omega$ be the
>   region between $\Gamma_6$ and $\Gamma_7$.
>
> Let $f$ be a function that is holomorphic in an open neighborhood of
>   $\overline \Omega$. Prove that there are functions $f_+$ and $f_-$ where $f_+$
>   is holomorphic in $S_7$, $f_-$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \overline{S_6}$, and $$f(z) = f_+(z) + f_-(z),$$ for all $z \in \Omega$.

[image]

My goal is to write $f(z)$ as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\frac{b_n}{z^n}$, where the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges
in a radius of $\frac{7}{2}\sqrt{2}$ and the Laurent series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{z^n}$ converges outside a radius of 3.  I begin with what I think is obvious
$$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{6.5}} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}} d\zeta.$$
$$b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{6.5}} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{-n+1}} d\zeta.$$
(Here $\Gamma_{6.5}$ is the boundary of the square with side length 6.5).

Let $f_+(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, and $f_-(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\frac{b_n}{z^n}$.  I suspect that these are the functions I need, but I'm struggling to show that $f_+$ and $f_-$ are defined on
$\Omega$ (i.e.,  the radii of convergence of $f_+(z)$ and
$f_-(\frac{1}{z})$ are at least $\frac{7}{2}\sqrt{2}$ and at most 3
respectively) and that $f = f_- + f_+$.

Any hints or solutions are appreciated!

Comment: Did you want "$f_$is holomorphic in $\mathbb C \setminus \bar {S_6}$?

Comment: Why not defined $f_{+}(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_7} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}$ and show $f_{+}$ is holomorphic on $S_7$ directly?
Tools you may find useful are [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) and for double integral of a continuous function over unit square, you can switch the order of integration!

Comment: @achillehui What is $f(\zeta)$ for $\zeta \in \Gamma_7$?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, you are right. Fixed that and another missing `\overline`. Thank you!

@achillehui The function may not be defined inside $S_6$. 

@zhw. Actually, that part isn't wrong: $f$ is defined on an open set containing $\overline \Omega$.

Comment: @Snow, the integral defining $f_{+}$ integrate only over points on $\Gamma_7$, it is defined for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \Gamma_7$ (and hence inside $S_6$). What you remains to prove is that integral, as a function of $z$, is analytic inside the whole $S_7$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer is you are being too ambitious in what you want to show. If you could do that, it would show any holomorphic $f$ on $\Omega$ extends holomorphically to an annular region strictly larger than $\Omega.$ That's not going to work.

Let $\Gamma_r$ be the square of side $r$ centered at the origin. Suppose $z \in \Omega.$ Then for $6<r_1<r_2<7$ with $r_1$ close to $6$ and $r_2$ close to $7,$ we have

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{r_2}}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -z}\, d\zeta - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{r_1}}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -z}\, d\zeta.$$

The first integral defines a holomorphic function in the interior of $\Gamma_{r_2},$ the second integral defines a holomorphic function in the exterior of $\Gamma_{r_1}.$ Play around with that idea for a bit.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to think about this. Meanwhile, you are missing close parenthesis after your $\zeta$'s in both `\frac`'s.

Comment: Also, since the domain of $f$ is an open set containing $\overline \Omega$ you can set $r_1 = 6$ and $r_2 = 7$.

Comment: Both integrals are defined and holomorphic everywhere except on the curves $\Gamma_{r_2}$ and $\Gamma_{r_1}$ respectively because of @achillehui's comment. The equality is seen by making a contour around a simply connected region (break the square annulus with a small gap) and then recognizing that the RHS is a Cauchy integral around this curve. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll leave this as it is, because it points the way to a solution if $f$  is assumed to only be holomorphic on $\Omega.$