# Laurent Series on a Square Annulus Confusion

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, laurent-series

I am attempting to solve the problem listed here: [Laurent Series on a square annulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590022/laurent-series-on-a-square-annulus)

and I tried the following approach because I didn't quite understand the accepted answer. I am wondering if this is valid or if I've gone off the rails somehow.

*Proof:*

$S_7$ is simply connected and not all of $\mathbb C$ so by the Riemann mapping theorem, there exists $\phi:S_7\to\mathbb D$ a conformal map where $\phi(0)=0$ and $\mathbb D$ is the open unit disk. (Sketchy) Since $\phi$ takes the boundary of $S_7$ to a circle and since $\phi$ is conformal, $\phi$ takes the boundary of $S_6$ to a circle too. That is, $\phi(S_6)=\mathbb D_r$ where $r<1.$ We can now see that $\phi\circ f$ is analytic on the annulus $A_{r,1}$ and by Laurent's theorem there exists a unique decomposition into series: $\phi\circ f(z)=\sum a_nz^n +\sum b_nz^n$ where the first part is analytic on $\mathbb D$ and the second is analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus \overline{\mathbb{ D_r}}.$

Then, we could set $f_+=\phi^{-1}(\sum a_nz^n)$ and $f_-=\phi^{-1}(\sum b_nz^n)$?

**Question 1:** Is this proof valid?

**Question 2:** I don't see how the answer from the cited question can solve part b) of the problem: "How many different ways are there of writing $f$ as the sum of $f_+$ and $f_−$ as in part (a)? Find all possible ways." It makes more sense to me to try and cite uniqueness in Laurent's Theorem.

Comment: If $\phi$ is conformal in the interior of $S_7$, then the angle between the images of the sides of $S_6$ must still be a right angle. It won't be a circle.

Comment: For part (b) you can start from two such decompositions $f_++f_-=f=g_++g_-$. Then $f_+-g_+=g_-f_-$ are two holomorphic functions, the left in $S_7$ and the right in the exterior of $S_6$. So, they extend each other to an entire function. So, once you have one such decomposition $f=f_++f_-$, you can get all other decompositions by taking an arbitrary entire function $h$ and writing $f=(f_++h)+(f_--h)$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I would upvote you but I don't have enough rep. That makes sense. Thank you